# "Access Denied" trying to execute a command using alternate credentials

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Due to reasons I won't bore you with, I'm locked into a very narrow set of circumstances to solve this problem.  The root problem is simple:  I need to copy the contents of a remote share to the local drive of a computer that has no current user, from BES.  BES runs as SYSTEM, which has no access to this share, so I have to access it using alternative credentials (which are easy to provide).  And I can't run as a service because the moment the service takes it, BES moves on and reboots the box, before the copy can complete.

TLDR; Need to execute a command using alternative credentials and it's not working.

I'm trying Powershell (but am open to darn near anything).  Here's my script:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process testbat.cmd -WorkingDirectory c:\temp\runas -Credential ($credentials)
```

If I'm logged into the box and run this, on any account, it runs and uses the credentials I provide.  However, if I run the script as SYSTEM (how the script will be run), I get:

> Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.
>   At C:\temp\runas\testrun.ps1:5 char:14
>   + Start-Process <<<<  testbat.cmd -WorkingDirectory c:\temp\runas -Credential (
>   $credentials)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Again, I'm open to almost anything, VBS, batch, etc.  I just can't:

1. Run it as a service, because BES considers the process "done" the moment it hands it off
2. Add any .exe's (it's a closed manufacturing environment) or foreign applications

Any wisdom, guidance, or just plain bonking me in the head for making a dumb mistake is appreciated.  I've not done much power shell, but I love how easy it is.  I've done a few scripts but this is my first hard stop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if `username` is actually granted access to `C:\temp\runas`.

Comment: Does the alternate credential account have the logon as a service user right?

Comment: Yes to both.  If I log in as my own personal account and run the script, it runs as "username".  Username is in the Administrator's group and has NTFS access to the share (Everyone does, in truth) and has log in as service as well as batch.

Comment: Oh, and SYSTEM does as well.  SYSTEM both has "logon as service" and NTFS rights to the directory.

Comment: Is there a reason you are running a batch file instead of just copying the files within the powershell script?

Comment: Beyond not knowing how to do that, nope.  It's an external share, so SYSTEM can't get to it, which means using my alt creds.  I will happily accept that as an answer if you can point me to the syntax.

Comment: One thing to note, it's not a file I'm copying, but a directory structure and files.  The batch file runs Robocopy, so if I move that functionality to powershell it needs to also get the subdirs.  Playing with BitsTransfer, it doesn't seem to do that, so looking for other solutions.

Comment: And Copy-Item doesn't seem to support alt creds by design.

Comment: Well, kind of. In PowerShell 1 & 2 the FileSystem provider did not support it, but that changed in PSv3. Are you using PowerShell 3 or higher?

Comment: 2.0.  Yet another limitation.  This is a small problem, but environmental issues are making it a beast.

Comment: Oh! Can you add 'Domain Computers' to the share's security? Then if it's a domain joined computer you don't need the alternative credentials. Not exactly a powershell resolution, but it should work for you.